# Building complex SQL command

Tags: sql, firebird

I am using sql for select, update, insert and some other features, but only simple ones until now. Now I need to write a complex command.

I have looked at using `case` but I do not know how to implement it.

This is what it should look like:

```
SELECT KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ID AS ISTORIJAID, KVIZ_PITANJA.PITANJE1, ~TACNO~
FROM KVIZ_ISTORIJA 
INNER JOIN KVIZ_PITANJA ON KVIZ_ISTORIJA.PITANJEID = KVIZ_PITANJA.PITANJEID 
WHERE REZULTATID = 12
```

I used `~TACNO~` to point out where I need a conditional value.

How I would write the condition in C# is like this (I will use column names from table as variables):

```
int ~TACNO~ = -1;
int I = -1;

if(KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR1_TACAN == 1)
    I = 1;
else if(KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR2_TACAN == 1)
    I = 2;
else if(KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR3_TACAN == 1)
    I = 3;
else if(KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR4_TACAN == 1)
    I = 4;
else if(KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR5_TACAN == 1)
    I = 5;

switch(I)
{
    case 1:
        if(KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO1 = 1)
            ~TACNO~ = 1;
       break;
    case 2:
        if(KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO2 = 1)
            ~TACNO~ = 1;
       break;
    case 3:
        if(KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO3 = 1)
            ~TACNO~ = 1;
       break;
    case 4:
        if(KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO4 = 1)
            ~TACNO~ = 1;
       break;
    case 5:
        if(KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO5 = 1)
            ~TACNO~ = 1;
       break;
}
```

How can I write the equivalent of this C# condition in SQL query?

Comment: Use "Searched case" variant as described at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-expressions.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case

Comment: I can use it instead of switch but what about first part (storing `I`)

Comment: You do not need intermediate `I` at all. You can set value for `TACNO` in the if-ladder directly.

Comment: It need to gets `1`. I use it as boolean

Comment: I cannot use only if-ladder. In first table I check which `answer` is correct, in second table I see which `answer` user picked up. Then I check if user picked correct `answer`. Is there way to use `WHERE CONDITION && CONDITION`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174868/discussion-between-aleksa-ristic-and-arioch-the).

Comment: First of all, you made a typical novice mistake was putting same values into different columns. You have to remake the table, so there would be one `KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO` column, and 5 rows with some ID =1...5. That is anti-SQL, anti-relational. Now you struggle with consequences and there would be more and more. Same way there should be one column `KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR_TACAN` and 5 rows with ID = 1 to 5. Restructure the database before it is too late....

Comment: I know that and I did it on purpose. Thank you for helping. I worked it out :)

Comment: If to talk in C terms, your function has to be like this: `int TACNO(){ for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) if( KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR[i]_TACAN == 1 && KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO[i] ==1 ) return +1; return -1;}` - again no if ladders (BTW, your switch is wrong, it does not COMPARE values with 1, it SETS values to 1, you mistook == and =)

Comment: Ops. It was wrote in second so made mistake since not writing in editor but here with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a searched [`CASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case) like this:

```
case 
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR1_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO1 = 1) then 1
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR2_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO2 = 1) then 1
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR3_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO3 = 1) then 1
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR4_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO4 = 1) then 1
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR5_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO5 = 1) then 1
  else -1
end
```

You could also do it as a single `when` clause, by joining the conditions using `OR`, but I think that is less readable:

```
case 
  when (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR1_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO1 = 1)
    or (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR2_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO2 = 1)
    or (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR3_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO3 = 1)
    or (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR4_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO4 = 1)
    or (KVIZ_PITANJA.ODGOVOR5_TACAN = 1 and KVIZ_ISTORIJA.ODGOVORENO5 = 1) then 1
  else -1
end
```

But as suggested by Arioch'The in the comments: consider normalizing your design, so you don't have repeating columns in a single table, but instead multiple rows with a discriminator column. It would simplify things like this.

Comment: I have already done it like you showed in first example but still thanks for posting this for future troubleshooters.